# PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE returns AMD64 in some 32-bit processes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, environment-variables, x86-64

I ran into a bizarre scenario where a 32 bit process claims that its PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE is AMD64, causing failure in components that make decisions based on that flag.

I isolated it to these steps:

- In VS2010, Create a Library project
- In the Project properties / Debug tab, set Start External Program to the VS exe (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe)
- Do Ctrl-F5 to run, which launched another VS instance
- In this second instance, create a Console app and paste the following code

In Main:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"));
Console.ReadLine();
```

- Now run the Console app

And it displays AMD64, even though it's a 32 bit process (the default for Console apps, per Build settings).

**Question**: can others repro this as well, and if so can you explain it?

Note: if you're curious, the reason I run VS this way is that I'm using an experimental hive for the second instance

UPDATE: note that in my real scenario, I'm not looking up this environment variable myself.  Instead, I use a component (SQLCE) which looks it up and relies on it being correct.

Comment: PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE is actually per process. e.g. if you run the console app directly from the first VS, it'll say x86. Note that I'm not looking up the env variable myself. I'm using a component (SQLCE 4.0) which is itself looking it up (to pick the right set of native binaries), so it's not under my control.

Comment: I've tried it myself only to find that following your steps doesn't allow me to execute.  [Error Image](http://imgur.com/FOoR8.png).  Apparently the build settings for the project targets 64-bit?  I noticed that by default, the active platform is set to "X64" rather than "Any CPU".

Comment: @Jeff: actually for me the default target is 32 bit. Strange error that you're getting, can't explain it! What if you set the target to 32 bit?

Comment: Ah you know what, I ran it in debug mode... whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my findings, I think I can come up with a reasonable explanation for this.

By having a project set to target "Any CPU" (the default for class libraries), the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable will be set to what's most capable when running the external process, "AMD64" for a 64-bit OS.  However since the Visual Studio IDE is actually a 32-bit process running with WOW, this can be confusing to processes started from within the second instance.

Forcing the library to target the 32-bit platform explicitly will set things correctly I've found.  Perhaps you should do that.

Comment: p.s., You don't necessarily have to run Visual Studio as the external process.  A command prompt will do nicely.  Then you can examine the environment variables there.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right! Though it feels like there is a bug somewhere. You'd think that PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE would be set by the OS based on the true bitness of the process, but I guess not...

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but why do you not simply test the value of `IntPtr.Size`? If it's 4 then you're 32-bit, if it's 8 then you're 64-bit.

.NET framework 4 also has the [Is64BitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx) and [Is64BitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx) properties, which would definitely be the way to go moving forward...

Comment: See the UPDATE in the question: this is not something I'm testing myself.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know, the PROCESSOR_ARHITECTURE it's not the hardware processor, it's referring to the processor that the OS software was made for.

Since AMD were the first that created 64-bit arhitecture (x86-64), Microsoft put support into the OS for this, and left the title that AMD initialy gave it. AMD64 and Intel64 refer in fact to the same x86-64 architecture so they are compatible.

You could try for example to get PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER and figure out the type of the processor from the information inside this.

Someone can correct me if i'm wrong here.

Comment: I believe that PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE is supposed to be set for each process. Also, note that launching the Console app above directly makes it display "x86", so it's something strange going on with VS being launched by VS.